# Jquery append() disables function of buttons and textboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, latex, equation

I am trying to make a LaTex equation creator that allows user to type in LaTex code into the textboxes and output a LaTex equation on real time.

The second function uses append() in order to allow users to duplicate multiple textboxes with multiple output divs (each one having a unique id of course) where if you type in an equation textbox #2, the LaTex output would be displayed on output div#2. This means that the user can create multiple LaTex equations at realtime.

However when I tested my code out, the first textbox (textbox_0), output div (result_0), and create equation button (btn_0) (where I did not create an equation) works flawlessly. However when I create an equation textbox, forming a second textbox and output div (textbox_1 and result_1), the two of them don't work at all, and it is only the original create equation button that can create other textboxes, output divs, and create equation buttons.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var find_match_id = 0;
    var id_int = 0;
    </script>

</head>
<body>


<table>
    <ol>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="results_0">Type in a LaTex equation. . .</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="search_text_0" onkeyup="findmatch(0);"><button id="btn0">Create Equation</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ol>
</table>


</body>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn"+(find_match_id)+"").click(function(){

    var id_int = find_match_id;
    find_match_id = find_match_id + 1;


    $("ol").append("<tr><td><div id='results_"+(find_match_id)+"'>Type in an equation. . .</div></td><td><input type='text' id='search_text_"+(find_match_id)+" onkeyup='findmatch("+(find_match_id)+");'/><button id='btn"+(find_match_id)+"'>Create Equation</button></td></tr>");

  });
});

function findmatch(id_int){
    var word = document.getElementById('search_text_'+(id_int)+'').value;
    var text = '<img src="http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?' + word + '"/>';

    document.getElementById('results_'+(id_int)+'').innerHTML = text;

}

</script>
</html>
```

Does anyone have any idea what the problem is and what should I do?

Comment: why are you appending a `TR` to a `OL`?  You shouldnt do that.

Comment: Also, can you create a www.jsfiddle.net example with your code?

Comment: The button click is only bound to the original button, you would need to look at using something like jQuery's .on() method or bind each button you create.

Comment: you are deleting the delegated event. read the section about delegation.http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there seems to be a missing quotation mark after defining your search_text_# id

```
id='search_text_"+(find_match_id)+" onkeyup='findmatch("
```

Should have a single quote here **_________**^

```
id='search_text_"+(find_match_id)+"' onkeyup='findmatch("
```

Second, the .click() function is only initialized on your very first button, you create other buttons but never assign a new click handler to it.  You will have to find the button and assign a click handler to it right after your append.  You can also use a wider scoped 'bind' method to just bind all buttons current or future to your callback, it would look something like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '[id^="btn"]', function() {
  .. your append logic ..
});
```

the selector syntax 'id^=' implies that the id should start with the following value, so any element starting with the id 'btn' will be handled by this click handler.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <ol>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="results_0">Type in a LaTex equation. . .</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="search_text_0" onkeyup="findmatch(0);"><button id="btn0" class="btn">Create Equation</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ol>
</table>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.btn', function(){
    var id_int = find_match_id;
    find_match_id = find_match_id + 1;
    $("ol").append("<tr><td><div id='results_"+(find_match_id)+"'>Type in an equation. . .</div></td><td><input type='text' id='search_text_"+(find_match_id)+"' onkeyup='findmatch("+(find_match_id)+");'/><button id='btn"+(find_match_id)+"' class='btn'>Create Equation</button></td></tr>"); 
  });
});
```

Use **event delegation method** for dynamically created elements. Also use class selector instead of id selector.

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/s5rDB/5/

Comment: I think that will still only bind the original button as the ID will be 0 when that code is evaluated.

Comment: @rufio86, Please check demo. Button Id has been updated to 0,1,2,3...n.

Comment: Seems that the previous 'Create Equation' buttons don't work, only the latest one does.

Comment: This method works for the adding equations part, but its secondary function is that if you type in a textbox (more specifically LaTex code), then the display div right next to it will go from "Type in an equation" to the actual LaTex output.

With my method, the original textbox at least work but when I copy and paste the find math function in your jsfiddle to update the output div with LaTex in realtime, it did not work.

Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: @user3377126, Can you please create fiddle demo for your issue?

Answer (score 0):

+First of all, you don't need to use `<ol>` instead of appending from `<table>` like this:

jQuery:

```
$("table").append("<tr><td><div id='results_"+    (find_match_id)+"'>Type in a LaTex equation</div></td><td><input type='text' id='search_text_"+(find_match_id)+"'/> <button id='btn"+(find_match_id)+"'>Create Equation</button></td></tr>");
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="results_0">Type in a LaTex equation</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="search_text_0" />
            <button id="btn0">Create Equation</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

+Second, you just need to use only one variable `find_match_id` so deleting the other one:

jQuery:

```
var find_match_id = 0;
```

+Third, like @Lochemage already said, you can use jQuery function '.on()' to attach event handler functions for 'click' and 'keyup' events to the selected elements that are 'input' and 'button'. Take a look at important changes in my demo below. '' now can change according to its neighbor '' using 'find_match_id'. Below is noticeable change in 'keyup' event to retrieve correct id for using in

jQuery:

```
var id = $(this).prop("id");
id = id.substring(12,13);
$("#results_"+id).html(text);
```

Hope this can help you out. Thanks @Lochemage for your helpful answer.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jasperlee/Tq8hH/